# Invalid JSON text passed

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I am having a problem merging json files via ssh. I always get the error

```
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq
```

Even though I pass a vlid json text.

```
# check if the content of the input file is valid JSONn  
if ! echo "$content" | jq empty > /dev/null 2>&1; then                                               
    echo "ERROR: The content of the input file is not valid JSON."
    exit 1                                                                                        
fi                                                                
                                                 
# extract the text inside the curly brackets from the JSON content                  
extracted_content=$(echo "$content" | jq .)    
  
# check if the extracted content is valid JSON                       
if ! echo "$extracted_content" | jq empty > /dev/null 2>&1; then              
    echo "ERROR: The content of the input file contains no or invalid curly braces."  
    exit 1                                                  
fi                                                                

while read ip 
do                                                                                                                         
        echo "Doing changes to machine $ip"
                                                                            
        # --- Connect to machine ---        

                 
        cd /home/root/.ssh                                                                 
        ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i sac_key root@${ip} -p22222 <<- _connect_      

        # --- Append the extracted content to the target JSON ---                       
        if ! jq --argjson data "$extracted_content" '. += $data' "$TO" > "$TO.tmp"; then
           echo "ERROR: Error appending content to destination JSON." 
           exit 1                                       
        fi    

        # --- Rename the temporary file to the original target ---
        mv "$TO.tmp" "$TO"     
_connect_                   
done < $1
```

So I tried to change the line

```
if ! jq --argjson data "$extracted_content" '. += $data' "$TO" > "$TO.tmp"; then
```

like doing only $extracted_content or like $(cat $extracted_content).
Or showing me the contenct of $extracted_content with echo

```
extracted conent before ssh =
{"ntpServers":"10.9.221.1"}
```

Also using a json validator (https://jsonformatter.net/json-validator/) to check if the file is valid.

Comment: Reduce your shown code until only the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Phillippe is good, but not perfect, because it requires you to escape the code in your heredoc yourself. Better practice is to have the shell do that escaping for you: Write the code you want to run remotely in a function, then tell the shell to serialize that function with `declare -f` just the same as how you serialize the data the function uses with `declare -p`.

```
remote_function() {

    # --- Append the extracted content to the target JSON ---
    jq --argjson data "$extracted_content" '. += $data' "$TO" > "$TO.tmp" || {
       rc=$?
       echo "ERROR: Error appending content to destination JSON." 
       exit "$rc"
    }

    # --- Rename the temporary file to the original target ---
    mv "$TO.tmp" "$TO"
}

ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i sac_key root@"$ip" -p22222 <<-_connect_
  $(declare -p extracted_content TO)  # define remote variables
  $(declare -f remote_function)       # define remote function
  remote_function                     # call remote function
_connect_
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variable extracted_content (via `declare`) and then escape the dollar ($) sign (for `extracted_content` and `data`):

```
ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i sac_key root@${ip} -p22222 <<- _connect_
        $(declare -p extracted_content)
        # --- Append the extracted content to the target JSON ---                       
        if ! jq --argjson data "\$extracted_content" '. += \$data' "$TO" > "$TO.tmp"; then
           echo "ERROR: Error appending content to destination JSON." 
           exit 1                                       
        fi    

        # --- Rename the temporary file to the original target ---
        mv "$TO.tmp" "$TO"     
_connect_
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm writing my own alternative that uses `declare -f` as well so the OP doesn't need to add backslashes by hand and worry about whether they were placed everywhere necessary. (For example, here you're vulnerable to shell injections via the value of `TO`, since it wasn't likewise passed through `declare -p` with references escaped).

Answer (score 1):

According to what your posted, the content of `extracted_content` is `{"ntpServers":"10.9.221.1"}`. Interpolating this into your heredoc produces

```
 jq --argjson data "{"ntpServers":"10.9.221.1"}" '. += $data'
```

After the shell resolves the quotes, `jq` receives the following arguments:

- Argument 1:  `--argjson`
- Argument 2:  `data`
- Argument 3:  `{ntpServers:10.9.221.1}
- Argument 4:  `. += XXX`

where XXX is the content of your variable `data`. You don't set this variable in the code you posted, so I guess it is an environment variable inherited from the parent process. If it's really unset, argument 4 becomes just `. +=` .

So the arguments to `jq` simply don't look right.

Comment: Agreed. In the heredoc use `jq --argjson data '$extracted_content'` with single quotes

Comment: @glenn jackman, That's no better as it will fail if the JSON contains single quotes. Avoid [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs!